# How to add a html button with angularjs with a working ng-click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am working on a game made with angularjs. I have one problem that I haven't been able to solve yet. I would like to use a popup dialog ( no alert ) whose content depends on the context. This popup contains a button, that when clicked starts the game.

Since the content is dynamic the ng-click function does not work.

I've tried with directives and straight from the controller but have not gotten it to work.

My concrete question is how do I add HTML Button to a  with angularjs that contains a ng-click function that will actually fire?

Edit: here one attempt (that actually gets the button to show, but ng-click does nothing):
Controller:

```
    {
       if ($scope.quiz.state === 'finished' || $scope.quiz.state === 'initialized') {
           var startButton = '<br><br><button data-ng-click="startQuiz">start quiz</button>';
           $scope.popupText = $sce.trustAsHtml('Stating ' + quiz.name + startButton);
           $scope.showStart = false;
           $scope.showPopup = true;
       }
    };
    $scope.startQuiz = function() {
        $scope.showPopup = false;
        if ($scope.quiz.state === 'initialized') {
             $scope.quiz.start();
             $scope.quizTimer.start($scope, $timeout);
        }
    };
```

Html:

```
<div id="popupBox">
    <div id="closePopup" data-ng-click="closePopup()">X</div>
    <div data-ng-bind-html="popupText"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: we can't guess how you are trying to do this without seeing some code

Comment: I would think you would want to do something like ng-click="$rootscope.broadcast(event, data)". Have whatever controller starts your game listening for the event.

Comment: You should mark your own answer as the correct one in order to make clear that the problem is solved. you can upvote other helpful answers apart from that.

Comment: I purposely haven't marked my answer as correct yet, because I am not convinced that it is the best. I am waiting for feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the help from the other answers I got it to work by doing the following (this is probably not the best way, but it works. Please comment if there is someway to improve this.):

Controller:

```
    ...
    $scope.compiledStartPopupText = $compile(angular.element('<br><br><button data-ng-click="startQuiz()">start quiz</button>'))($scope);
    $scope.popupText = 'Starting ' + $scope.quiz.name;
    $scope.getCompiledStartPopupText = function() {
        return $scope.compiledStartPopupText;
    };
    $scope.openStartQuizPopup = function()
    {
        if ($scope.quiz.state === 'finished' || $scope.quiz.state === 'initialized') {
            if($scope.quiz.state === 'finished') {
                $scope.quiz.reinitialize();
            }
            $scope.showPopup = true;
        }
    };
    $scope.closePopup = function() {
        $scope.showPopup = false;
        if($scope.quiz.state !== 'started') {
            $scope.showStart = true;
        }
    };
    $scope.startQuiz = function() {
        $scope.showStart = false;
        $scope.showPopup = false;
        if ($scope.quiz.state === 'initialized') {
            $scope.quiz.start();
            $scope.quizTimer.start($scope, $timeout);
        } else if ($scope.quiz.state === 'finished') {
            $scope.quiz.restart();
            $scope.quizTimer.restart($scope, $timeout);
        }
    };
    $scope.endGame = function()
    {
        $scope.quiz.state = 'finished';
        $scope.showPopup = true;
        $scope.showStart = true;
    };
    ...
```

Directive:

```
    directive('popUp', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function($scope, elm, attrs) {
                $scope.$watch('quiz.state', function(value){
                    if(value === 'finished') {
                        elm.html('finished');
                    } else {
                        var compiledStartButton = $scope.getCompiledStartPopupText();
                        elm.html($scope.popupText);
                        elm.append(compiledStartButton);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    };
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="popup" ng-show="showPopup">
        <div id="popupBox">
            <div id="closePopup" data-ng-click="closePopup()">X</div>
            <div data-pop-up class="cta"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Since no feedback has come, I have marked this answer. Still if there is anything I could do better please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to call `closePopup()`, let's say your app is initialized at the top of the html and you have a `ng-controller="MsgCtrl"` as well, within the controller have your code

```
<div id="popupBox">
    <div id="closePopup" data-ng-click="closePopup()">X</div>
    <div data-ng-bind-html="popupText"></div>
</div>
```

and then in the script of your app, write something like this

```
function MsgCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.closePopup = function () {
        console.log("function called");
    };
}
```

Look at this for a [similar example](http://jsfiddle.net/combizs/sSyYa/) and experiment with it.

Comment: Thanks, but getting the popup to close was not the problem. I needed to change the text of the popup and add a button for the user to click when starting.

Answer (score 2):

By using the [$compile service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile), you can evaluate arbitrary HTML in the context of a certain scope. Example:

```
var element = $compile(angular.element('<button ng-click="doSomething()"></button>'))(scope);
```

The variable `element` then contains an angular.element (or jQuery if you are using it) that you can insert anywhere in the DOM. Clicking the button will result in an invocation of `scope.doSomething()`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks this added another piece to the puzzle. I wasn't quite sure where to add "element" at first. In the end I decided to use it in the directive.